# Best practice for Flutter widget hierarchy

Tags: flutter

From reading https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html and various examples online, I get the impression that the "best practice" layout hierarchy for Flutter is as follows:

```
MaterialApp
⮡ Scaffold
  ⮡ AnnotatedRegion (optional)
    ⮡ SafeArea (optional)
```

My question:

Considering performance (if any) and best practice, where should I put e.g. `FutureBuilder`, `OrientationBuilder` and MobX's `Observer` if they happen to be *global* wrappers?

Answer (score 1):

I usually put my global wrappers between MaterialApp and Scaffold, reason being that MaterialApp is your router, and if the app has authentication, I put that stream in front of global wrappers. So I find best practice to look like this:

```
MaterialApp (Theme and Route)
⮡ Router (Optional - something like Fluro Router)
  ⮡  AuthStream (Using StreamProvider - Checks whether user is logged in or not, if not returns to Login)
    ⮡ Wrapper (Holds my Future Builders)
      ⮡  Scaffold
```

[Fluro Router](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro)

[StreamProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html)